# Unable to install libpam0g-dev with unmet dependencies error, but unable to install dependencies

Tags: dependencies

Trying to install OpenSSH 8.5p1 from source, and installing libpam0g-dev, i'm encountering this error:

```
"The following packages have unmet dependencies:", " libpam0g-dev : Depends: libpam0g (= 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2) but 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2.18.04.1 is to be installed"]}
```

This is on Ubuntu 18.04.2.

Comment: Did you remember to run `sudo apt update` first to get the package catalog up to date?

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy libpam0g-dev libpam0g`?

Comment: Yes, i did both sudo apt update and upgrade.

Comment: $ apt-cache policy libpam0g-dev
libpam0g-dev:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2
  Version table:
     1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2.3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages

Comment: $ apt-cache policy libpam0g
libpam0g:
  Installed: 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2.18.04.1
  Candidate: 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2.18.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2.18.04.1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.1.8-3.6ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2.3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1.1.8-3.2ubuntu2 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages